# Convert an entire string to a dummy variable

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have 30+ feature but I need to convert 2 features into dummy variables. The 2 features are the name of the Winner and the Loser. You can see in the photo below the features. I want to see the conversion to a dummy type of the names in the same position for every row.

I don't understand how to use the method to convert to a dummy variable. Anyone can give me an idea? Thank you in advance. [You can find the picture here with the features so you can understand what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u31xk.png)

Comment: don't post images of your code, copy and paste what you have tried so far and where is the problem.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `.get_dummies()`? Wouldn't one hot encoding from scikit-learn be better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Alex97:

The method `pd.get_dummies` should answer your issue.

### Solution

```py
df # your DataFrame as shown on your picture

# generate dummies
dum_winners = pd.get_dummies(df.Winner, prefix="win", prefix_sep=" ")
dum_losers = pd.get_dummies(df.Loser, prefix="los", prefix_sep=" ")

# update df with dummies
df = pd.concat([df, dum_winners, dum_losers], axis=1)\
    .drop(columns=["Winner", "Loser"])
```

The solution above get as input:

```
   Other Features    Winner     Loser
0               2   John D.  Jason S.
1               4  Jason S.   Eric N.
```

and returns:

```
   Other Features  win Jason S.  win John D.  los Eric N.  los Jason S.
0               2             0            1            0             1
1               4             1            0            1             0
```

### Details

Here are documentation links:

- `concat` to merge DataFrames: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat)
- `get_dummies` to generate
  a one hot encoded matrix: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)